# code for (-) button of windows8 start screen

Tags: windows-8, startup

on click @ the "-" symbol present over the highlighted part of the image present @ http://www.freeimagehosting.net/2qjtc

the screen changes to the image @ http://www.freeimagehosting.net/8311b

i want to use the same feature in my application.

Can any one tell me how 2 use this feature.

sry fr giving url to images,[due to less reputation i am unable to post images]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Semantic Zoom.

You need to create two different views for you App and insert them into a `<SemanticZoom>` tag into your XAML.

The existing view for your App is the zoomed in view.

```
<SemanticZoom>

<SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    <!-- Put the GridView for the zoomed out view here. -->   
</SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>

<SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    <!-- Put the GridView for the zoomed in view here. -->       
</SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
```

Comment: how to do in case of app created using java script.

Comment: In HTML it's a Little bit more complicated. You have a full step by step tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465492.aspx